# How do I draw a box around an object in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, resize

There is a really handy way to size the page: "Resize page to drawing or selection". Is there a similar option for drawing boxes around a selection? I have a group of objects that I would like to draw a tight rectangle around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. *Group* your objects.
2. *Copy* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)
3. Draw some rectangle (its position and size do not matter).
4. Select your rectangle.
5. *Edit → paste size → paste size.*
6. Open the alignment tab and set *relative to* to *first selected.*
7. Select your group and then your rectangle.
8. Use *centre on vertical axis* and *centre on horizontal axis* from the alignment tab.

Comment: Thanks, I had to paste the sizes separately, but other than that it worked great.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution:

1. Group your objects:

[image: Group your objects]

2. Enable "Snap to bounding box corners" and "Snap bounding box corners":
   [image: bounding box1][image: bounding box2]
3. Draw a rectangle, any size:
   [image: Draw rect]
4. Resize the rectangle:
   [image: Resizing1]
   [image: Resizing2]

Final result:
[image: Result]